# How to check if a binary tree remains AVL and maintain it?

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I'm having some trouble with the creation of an AVL tree structure in C++ for a university project. So far, I managed to make simple add and delete functions, but here comes the problem! I 've seen some codes here where the checks are made in the add function directly, but I didn't want to copy the code. Is there a way to create a seperate function which does exactly this work? The thing I can't make work is how to make the program understand in which rotation case I have to go.

My code so far is this:

```cpp
struct node
{
    unsigned int target;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

int ClassInvertedIndex::Height(struct node *toCheck)
{
    int left, right;

    if(toCheck == NULL)
        return 0;
    left = Height(toCheck->left);
    right = Height(toCheck->right);
    if(left > right)
        return left+1;
    else
        return right+1;
}

void ClassInvertedIndex::maintainAVL(struct node *toCheck)
{
    if(Height(toCheck->left)-Height(toCheck->right) == 2);  //Left subtree problem.

    if(Height(toCheck->right)-Height(toCheck->left) == 2);  //Right subtree problem.
}


bool ClassInvertedIndex::addNode(unsigned int x)
{
    return insideAdd(data, x);
}



bool ClassInvertedIndex::insideAdd(struct node *toAdd, unsigned int x)
{
    if(toAdd == NULL)
    {
        toAdd = new struct node;

        if(toAdd == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Could not allocate memory.";
            return false;
        }

        toAdd->left = NULL;
        toAdd->right = NULL;
        toAdd->target = x;
        return true;
    }

    else if(x < toAdd->target)
    {
        bool result;
        result = insideAdd(toAdd->left, x);
        if(result)
        {
            //maintainAVL(toAdd);
        }
        return result;
    }

    else if(x > toAdd->target)
    {
        bool result;
        result = insideAdd(toAdd->right, x);
        if(result)
        {
            //maintainAVL(toAdd);
        }
        return result;
    }

    else       //x already exists.
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, in the maintainAVL method, what should I do to decide what rotation I need?

Comment: BTW, instead of if-else, if you write `return std::max(Height(toCheck->left),Height(toCheck->right) + 1;`, that would be better, as it is simple, concise and more readable.